# UDK Learning Help For A Software Engineer‏

Tags: unreal-development-kit, unrealscript

i am a Software Engineer and i have a Game Passion. I am learning Unreal Development Kit now a days. I just want to know that as a Software Engineer what areas of Unreal Development Kit should i learn? and what should i know of Unreal Development Kit as a Software Engineer so that i can easily work on Gaming field as a Unreal Development Kit developer.?

I am just watching [New boston Tutorial for UDK](http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=12)

I just need a proper way or path  to learn Unreal Development Kit so that i can furnish my skills and expertise on my passion.

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Unreal Development Kit as a Software Engineer you should know C++ , UnrealScript and Kismet.

UDK Videos:

1. Intro: UDK.com 3D Buzz Video Tutorials.
2. UDK Kismet :  [3dbuzz.com/training/view/unreal-development-kit/kismet](http://www.3dbuzz.com/training/view/unreal-development-kit/kismet).
3. UnrealScript: 3dbuzz.com (unreal-tournament-2003-2004 unrealscript ).

Books in Order of Importance 2013 :

1. UnrealScript: Unreal Development Kit Programming with UnrealScript (Must Read Books)(Reading Order 4° ).
2. UnrealScript: Unreal Development Kit Programming Cookbook (Reading Order 3° ).
3. UDK Kismet :  Mastering UDK Game Development (Reading Order 2° ).
4. UDK Kismet :  Unreal Development Kit Programming Game Design Cookbook (Reading Order 1° ).

Documentation :

1. [UDK.com General programming with native code and UnrealScript](http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/TechnicalHome.html).

Total time 1 or 2 Year.